# Direct sum decomposition of weight spaces and relation to Tensor products.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensor-products

There are 3 parts to the question that I am trying to understand, and while it is not homework it seems instrumental in decomposition modules into weight spaces and their relation to tensor products.

Let $L= sl(2,\mathbb{C})$, and let $V = \mathbb{C}^2$ be the "natural module" with the standard basis $v_1,v_2$. Now let  $W = \mathbb{C}^2$ be another copy of the "natural module":

$\textbf{Question 1}$: What is this "natural module"? What is the basis?

Now with respect to the basis $v_1 \otimes v_1$, $v_1 \otimes v_2$, $v_2 \otimes v_1$, $v_2 \otimes v_2$ one finds that the matrices of e, f, and g are:

$\rho (e) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ $\rho (f) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ $\rho (h) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \end{array}\right)$

$\textbf{Question 2}$: Where do these come from?  The only thing I can think of is that they are using e, f, and g which are elements of $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$ where $e = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ $f = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ $h = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right)$ as these are used as a basis for an exercise in the first chapter.

Now I can see that the eigenvalues of the 4 x 4 matrices are 0 and 2 hence finding the weights we have $V_0$ and $V_2$ and so we are building up the weight space and have $V_0 \oplus V_2$, I however am unsure of why I am told that $V \otimes W \simeq V_0 \oplus V_2$

$\textbf{Question 3}$: How do I find, in general an explicit direct sum decomposition of $V \otimes W$ into a direct sum of irreducible decompositions?

Any help on any 3 parts is very helpful, this is a roadblock for me. Also note that the 3rd part of the question is Exercise 15.2 from Erdmann and Wildon's book "Introduction to Lie Algebras".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the matrix lie algebras ${\frak gl}_n(k)$, ${\frak sl}_n(k)$, etc. are *by definition* the lie algebras comprised of certain linear transformations of the vector space $k^n$, we call $k^n$ the "natural" space (or module) on which the matrix lie algebras act.

---

You're correct; the matrix representations of the standard basis $e,f,g\in{\frak sl}_2(\Bbb C)$ are given by

$$e=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad f=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad h=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

The basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ on $V$ induces a basis on the tensor product $V\otimes V$, say $\{w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4\}$:

$$\begin{array}{ll} w_1=v_1\otimes v_1  & w_2=v_1\otimes v_2 \\ w_3=v_2\otimes v_1 & w_4=v_2\otimes v_2 \end{array}$$

If a lie algebra element acts by $A$ on $V$, then it acts by $x\otimes y\mapsto Ax\otimes y+x\otimes Ay$ on $V\otimes V$. If we use the relations $ev_1=0$, $ev_2=v_1$ we can compute how $e$ acts on $w_{1,2,3,4}$:

$$ew_1=e(v_1\otimes v_1)=ev_1\otimes v_1+v_1\otimes ev_1=0\otimes v_1+v_1\otimes 0=0.$$

$$ew_2=e(v_1\otimes v_2)=ev_1\otimes v_2+v_1\otimes ev_2=0\otimes v_2+v_1\otimes v_1=w_1 $$

and then you should get $ew_3=w_1$ and $ew_4=w_2+w_3$. Since we know how $e$ acts on the basis vectors $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ of $V\otimes V$, we can write down its matrix. You should get the matrix

$$\rho(e)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

You can use the same procedure to compute the matrices for $f$ and $h$.

---

Finding the irreducible representation decomposition of $V\otimes W$ is generally a hard problem. One often exploits specific features of $V$ and $W$ to get the job done, rather than use some uniform procedure. One can use bilinearity of the tensor product to reduce the problem of decomposing $V\otimes W$ for general $V,W$ to decomposing it for irreducible $V$ and $W$. And for that, I believe we can numerical invariants to compute he multiplicities. I know that for *group representations* (namely semisimple ones), we can compute the multiplicity of the irrep $U$ inside $V\otimes W$ as

$$\dim_{\Bbb C}\hom_{\Bbb C[G]}(U,V\otimes W)=\dim_{\Bbb C}\hom_{\Bbb C[G]}(\Bbb C,U^*\otimes V\otimes W)$$

$$=\dim_{\Bbb C}(U^*\otimes V\otimes W)^G=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_{U^*\otimes V\otimes W}(g)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_U(g^{-1})\chi_V(g)\chi_W(g).$$

Comment: "If we use the relations $ev_2=v_1$ and $ev_2=v_1$ "How does one decide this, i.e. what is $v_1$ and how are the relationships such as  $ew_4=w_2+w_3$ obtained?Perhaps someone could expound on the steps how one determines the action of $e$ on $v_x$

Comment: @Relative0 We're just computing $ ( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} ) ( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix})$ and $ ( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} ) ( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix})$. Linear algebra and being able to multiply vectors by matrices is a big prerequisite to studying lie algebras.

Comment: Thank you Whacka, yes, I know how to multiply matrices - what I didn't know was why one chose $( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix})$ and $( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix})$ as the basis.

Comment: Even still I am getting stumped on a couple of things, first wouldn't $v_1 \otimes v_1 = ( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix}) \otimes ( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix}) $ $= ( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix})$? Second, how are these sub-matrices placed inside of $\rho(e)$? I am using $v_1 \otimes v_2 = ( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} ), v_2 \otimes v_1 = ( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} )$, and $v_2 \otimes v_2 = ( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} )$

Comment: @Relative0 If you pick an ordered basis, then rewriting vectors as coordinate vectors means having the first basis vector be $(1,0,\cdots,0)$ and so on. That's the procedure for converting between abstract vector spaces and coordinate vector spaces, it's what allows us to take a linear transformation and write down an explicit matrix for it with respect to a basis. Then applying a linear transformation to a vector mirrors applying the corresponding matrix to the corresponding coordinate vector. This is all just linear algebra.

Comment: One way of writing tensor products of two vectors is as a matrix. I am not using that convention and recommend you not introduce it here. I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about when you mention putting tensor products like $v_1\otimes v_1$ inside $\rho(e)$. Here's the deal: we have four vectors $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ of a vector space and some linear transformation $\rho(e)$ acts on that space. For $i=1,2,3,4$, we can write $\rho(e)w_i$ as a linear combination of $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$, and looking at the coefficients is what allows us to write down the matrix for $\rho(e)$. Linear algebra.

Comment: Hello whacka, Seems I was overthinking things, I guess I don't understand why I am figuring out $\rho(e)$ for example, that I don't see what its future use will be. I did compute the elements of the particular matrices and see that $\rho(e)=\begin{pmatrix}e(w_4)\\e(w_3)\\e(w_2)\\e(w_1)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}w_4\\w_3\\w_2\\w_1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}w_2 + w_3\\w_1\\w_1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ But again, don't see why I am doing this computation - I think that would help if you have any more thoughts. Thanks either way.

Comment: @ThinkingInnovate You're the one who asked me how whatever you're reading found matrices for e.g. $\rho(e)$. (It's your `Question 2`.) I answered your question. What does your text use the matrices for? Presumably for further computations down the road, I'm not sure. I don't have your text so I can't look and see what they use it for.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\sl{\mathfrak{sl}} \def\C{\mathbb{C}}$

**Answer 1:** The natural module of $\sl_{2}$ is the two dimensional vector space $\C^{2}$ on which $\sl_{2}$ acts as $2 \times 2$ matrices of trace $0.$ The basis is the standard basis of $\C^{2}$.

**Answer 2:** So you notice that you have matrices that give the action of $e, f, h$ on the standard basis vectors of $V$ and $W$. Then, the action of (say) $e$ on (say) $v_{1} \otimes v_{2}$ is defined as

$$\rho(e)(v_{1} \otimes v_{2}) = e(v_{1}) \otimes v_{2} + v_{1} \otimes e(v_{2}).$$

You should be able to use the basis $v_{1} \otimes v_{1}, v_{1} \otimes v_{2}, v_{2} \otimes v_{1}, v_{2} \otimes v_{2}$ to compute the new matrices of $e, f, h$.

**Answer 3:** In general, taking two irreducible representations $V$ and $W$ of a semisimple lie algebra and finding the irreducible decomposition of $V \otimes W$ can be somewhat tricky to compute but there is an algorithm of sorts and it's nice and easy for $sl_{2}.$ I will elucidate using a more general example.

So, hopefully, you know that each irreducible representation of $sl_{2}$ is represented by a positive integer $n$ and that if $V$ corresponds to $n$, then the weight spaces of $V$ are one dimensional and go from $n$ to $-n$ in steps of $2$.

So, suppose $V$ corresponds to $n$ and $W$ corresponds to $m$. Then $\{V_{-n}, \ldots, V_{n}\}$ and $W_{-m}, \ldots, W_{m}\}$ are the weight spaces of $V$ and $W$, and we can write the weight space decomposition of $V \otimes W$ as

$$V \otimes W = \oplus_{i \in \{-n, - n+ 2, \ldots n\}, j \in \{-m, -m+2, \ldots, m\}} V_{i} \otimes W_{j}.$$

Now, we begin the decomposition by picking off highest weight vectors. The highest weight in $V \otimes W$ is $m+n$. So this gives us one irrep corresponding to $m+n$. We now delete one multiplicity from each of the the weights that belong to $V_{m+n}$ (one weight from $-(m+n)$ to $m+n$ increasing in multiples of $2$.) We then look at the highest weight remaining in $V \otimes W$. This gives us another irreducible which we can peel off of $V \otimes W$. We proceed this way until we exhaust all the weights of $V \otimes W$.

Note that at this point, you can actually construct combinatorial formulas which give you the irreducible decomposition but I just wanted to outline the general algorithm without obscuring it in details.

Let's go through the specific example with your $V$ and $W$. In your case, $V$ and $W$ are irreducible representations of dimension $2$ and hence highest weight $1$ (dimension is 1 + highest weight always for an irrep of $sl_{2}$.) Thus, the $V$ and $W$ have a total list of weights (with multiplicities) of $\{-1, 1\}$. Hence, $V \otimes W$ has weight spaces of weight -2, 0 (with multiplicity 2) and $2.$. The highest weight is $2$ so it contains $V_{2}$ as an irrep. This leaves just the weight $0$ with multiplicity 1 which corresponds to $V_{0}$.

Comment: A small comment about answer to (Q3) as both answers didn't mention it.  The (forumla for) decomposition of $V\otimes W$ for $V,W$ irreducible is usually called Clebsch-Gordan decomposition.